# React Component should mount previous state before fetching new data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

DataContext.js

```
export const DataContext = createContext()

const DataContext = ({ children }) => {
  const [userValue, setUserValue] = useState()
  const [user, setUser] = useState()

  const fetch = useCallback(async () => {
            const response = await axios(Url)
        setBalance(response.data)

      }
  }, [])
```

usePrevious.js

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

function usePrevious(value) {
  const ref = useRef()
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value
  })
  return ref.current
}

export default usePrevious
```

UsersData Component

```
import { DataContext } from '../context/DataContext'
import usePrevious from './usePrevious'

const UsersValue = () => {
  const { userValue} = useContext(DataContext)
  const prevData = usePrevious(useValue)

useEffect(() => {
  console.log('prevData ', prevData)
  console.log('userValue', userValue)
}, [useValue, prevData])

return (....)
```

Following the React documentation using usePrevious example.

When I render the component for the first time it takes few sec to load the data(async), this is fine, but if I route away to another link and come back, I still get the component loading the data and I want to fetch the previous state if the data has not changed

I was specting the console.log for prevData to show the previous state(when linked back to component) while component is fetching, but is just showing the same for userValue, both have the same state undefined, than data comes is available

How can I render a memorized state for the UsersData Component,to avoid loading all the time when component is mounting, I start looking into react.memo, is this the direction I need to take?

If so how can I implement React.memo in this case, thx

Answer (score 0):

I don't think usePrevious will help you if you are unmounting and re-mounting the component, the ref will be recycled. You could pass down the fetch function from the context, and call it in the child component when it mounts. This fetch would run in the context, and if there is a difference between the new and data stored in the context, update the userValue using setUserValue in the context. This change would then be passed down to the child after the state has been updated. If they are the same, do not call setUserValue and no update will occur.

The problem here is if there is a new value, the child component won't know until the fetch has finished. You may be displaying old data off the bat, but if you don't tell the user you are fetching, the child component may update unexpectedly when the fetch is finished and the context is updated.

[Caching is difficult](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-cache-invalidation-considered-difficult), you may just want to always provide a fresh value.

If you decide to go this route, you will need to check if the data you fetched has changed. If the data is an object and doesn't have functions added to it, a quick way is to use JSON.stringify on both objects and compare the stringified values.

Comment: Interesting input, thanks you, what you think is the pros and cons of using local storage for in this case?

Comment: Local storage would have the same issues, the bottleneck is the request to the server. Is this an expensive request? Some alternatives would be to add a button to the Component that says "update" which would trigger the fetch, but then then it is difficult to detect if data has changed. You could also look into using WebSockets to have the server push information if you are developing it. Big picture , it is easy to go down a rabbit hole of complexity  to try to solve a very small problem, which makes refactoring and debugging a nightmare in the future